# Injeção de dependência em handlers do gin em golang

Tags: golang, injeção-de-dependência

Eu tenho o seguinte código de um controller.go em go:

```
func CreateUserV1(ctx *gin.Context) {

    db_conn := db.Conn()
    repo := repository.NewUsersRepositoryPGX(db_conn)

    request := entity.User{}
    err := ctx.BindJSON(&request)
    if err != nil {
        ctx.Status(http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    // TODO: Validações, etc

    user, err := repo.Create(request)
    if err != nil {
        ctx.Status(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        log.Panicf("Falha ao cadastrar o usuário: %v", err)
    }

    ctx.JSON(http.StatusCreated, user)
}
```

Que é chamado em routes.go

```
func Register(router *gin.Engine) {

    v1 := router.Group("api/v1/users")
    {
        v1.POST("/", CreateUserV1)
    }

}
```

O código acima funciona perfeitamente, porém o que me incomoda são as seguintes linhas:

```
db_conn := db.Conn()
repo := repository.NewUsersRepositoryPGX(db_conn)
```

db_conn é uma conexão com o postgresql através do pgx, e repo é um repositório, porém penso que essa não é a forma correta de se injetar dependência em Go, pois se eu tiver que trocar o banco no meio do projeto irei ter que ir em cada controller trocando as linhas, estou acostumado com injeção em linguagens orientada a objetos convencionais como Java, Kotlin, C# etc, mas em Go isso me parece muito errado, existe uma maneira mais "correta" de se fazer o que estou fazendo visando manutenção e qualidade do código a longo prazo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acabei achando uma alternativa me baseando na documentação atual do gin:

no arquivo `controller.go` crio uma interface que deve implementar os métodos do controller, onde na sua implementação é passado o repositório:

```
type ControllerV1 interface {
    CreateUserV1(*gin.Context)
    LoginV1(*gin.Context)
}

type ControllerV1Impl struct {
    PgxConn         *pgx.Conn
    UsersRepository repository.UsersRepositoryPGX
}

func NewControllerV1(conn *pgx.Conn) *ControllerV1Impl {
    return &ControllerV1Impl{
        PgxConn:         conn,
        UsersRepository: *repository.NewUsersRepositoryPGX(conn),
    }
}
```

No `routes.go` eu crio o controller e passo a função para sua respectiva rota:

```
    controllerV1 := NewControllerV1(db.Conn())
    v1 := router.Group("api/v1/users")
    {
        v1.POST("/", controllerV1.CreateUserV1)
        v1.POST("/login", controllerV1.LoginV1)
    }
```

E por fim no arquivo de implementação do controller é passado o controller na função:

```
// Cria um novo usuário
// @Tags        users
// @Accept      json
// @Produce     json
// @Success     201 {object} entity.User
// @Failure     400 {object} entity.StandardResponse
// @Failure     400
// @Failure     500
// @Router      /users [post]
func (c *ControllerV1Impl) CreateUserV1(ctx *gin.Context) {

    *Restante da função*    

    // Insere no banco
    user, err := c.UsersRepository.Create(request)
    if err != nil {
        ctx.Status(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        log.Panicf("Falha ao cadastrar o usuário: %v", err)
    }

    ctx.JSON(http.StatusCreated, user)
}
```

Desta forma consegui utilizar melhor a injeção de dependência e trocar o repositório mais fácilmente se necessário por exemplo.